# Sync multiple PCs every boot via home LAN (local files update old version on server)

Tags: synchronization, file-server, lan

I need your precious support and advices for a kind of setup for my home computing.

So... I have two laptops and a desktop that I use same (or different) times. Every computer has a different distro (Arch for desktop, openSUSE for laptop1 and LinuxMINT for laptop2) with everyone its own purposes.

I also have a small SoC board.

And now my question...
I'd like to setup the small SoC as a **MASTER** with attached a 2TB eSATA HDD and put it inside my LAN (via eth).
What I need is that when I use one of the three computers, they sync specific folders with the "MASTER" and theese folders are taken up at every boot.

Example:
**MASTER** has unique partition of 2TB with: */dwn*, */doc*, */music*, */film*, */tv*, */pictures*, */src_build*.

I download the PDF of an invoice in ***PC2***/home/mysameusername/dwn, but then I move into ***PC2***/home/mysameusername/doc. Actually the file is saved in ***MASTER***/doc.

Then I turn on **PC3** and rip a DVD into ***PC3***/home/mysameusername/film; again, the file is actuyally saved in MASTER/film and I can read it from every others PCs.
The ripped DVD will be converted using PC1 and the converted file will be stored inside ***MASTER***/film; the original rip will be deleted after.
Then when it's time to transfer some photos from the phone to ***PC1***/home/mysameusername/pictures, the files will be actually stored in ***MASTER***/pictures.
After some time I travel, and save some photos inside ***PC2***/home/mysameusername/pictures; when I return home I'd like that **PC2** automatically saves new photos inside **MASTER**.
Ecc...

The result is:

**MASTER**[*/dwn*, */doc*, */music*, */film*, */tv*, */pictures*, */src_build*] will autosync on every boot desktop, laptop1, laptop2

And from every computer, files (and sub-folders) will be synced, modified, red, deleted, renamed, etc...

---

How is done this?
Can you pleas explain how to set-up or which online documentation should I look for?

Hope you could understand my idea / question, english is not my First language!

Thanks!

---

---

Ok... Thanks to @Panki comments I managed to clarify my doubts... So let me summarize!

1. *[This LDAP directory can be either local (installed on the same computer) or network (e.g. in a lab environment where central authentication is desired).](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LDAP_authentication)*
2. *[Setting up an OpenLDAP Server with SSL + NFS for User Home Directories](https://www.lisenet.com/2016/openldap-with-ssl-and-nfs-for-user-home-directories-on-centos-7/)*

1) This is what, indeed, I was looking for (THANKS to Paki to understand my real need)

2) Good: directories are taken up on boot from a server, but... What if I boot a computer outside from my home LAN?

Comment: Have you taken a look at `rsync`? Also, what is supposed to happen if the "Master" is not reachable, i.e. if you use the laptop outside of your LAN?

Comment: In fact... I mean, I'm away home several times. I'd like to autosync the new files as soon as the laptop is connected to my home LAN. Are you telling me I (almost) always have no local files in my laptops?

Comment: Uhh.. No, I'm not. Take a look at Nextcloud and similar, seems like it'd fit your purpose.

Comment: But I'd like to stay away from everything is cloud related... I don't want to costantly upload over the internet... I'm looking around, seems Windows has a way to login from a central machine and keep local files and also sync folders over LAN. Is Domain, am I right? Is there such a thing on Linux?

Comment: ... you can run the cloud at home and only sync when you're actually there. To your "domain" question, take a look at what `ldap` is.

Comment: @Panki, thanks. See updated question